# How to collect the url from the clicked article instead of the google.news site

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

The code below randomizes categories and selects the first article. You then get directed to the new site where the you can read the article. after waiting 10sec for the site to load (time.sleep(10). The problem is that the url from the newly loaded article isn't collected but instead its the news.google.com site. I want to collect the url of the newly loaded article, here is the code below. Any answer towards rectifying this would help.

code:

```
# Navigate to Google News
driver.get(f"https://news.google.com/topics/{random_category}")
time.sleep(5)

a = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article > div > a")))
print(f"Title: {a[0].get_attribute('aria-label')}")
a[0].click()
time.sleep(10)

# Get URL of article
article_url = driver.current_url
print(article_url)
```

Comment: can you please provide all of the imported libraries, and the `random_category` variable? I also noticed that when I navigate to "https://news.google.com", the `random_category` suffix in the URL is not plain English by a series of alphanumeric characters (eg "Business" category has the following URL: https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqKggKIiRDQkFTRlFvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0JXVnVMVWRDR2dKQlZTZ0FQAQ. Have you already captured a list of these potential suffixes to navigate to using `driver.get(url)`?

Comment: import os
import time
import schedule
import requests
import openai
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a few things:

1. You need to capture the current window handle because we're going to use it in a minute to switch to the new window.
2. Add a wait until the number of windows is 2.
3. Switch to the new window handle
4. Wait for the URL to NOT be on the news.google.com domain

Here's the working code

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

BUSINESS = 'CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?hl=enUS&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'
WORLD = 'CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx1YlY4U0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'

categories = [WORLD, BUSINESS]
random_category = random.choice(categories)

# Navigate to Google News
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(f"https://news.google.com/topics/{random_category}")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
a = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article > div > a")))
print(f"Title: {a[0].get_attribute('aria-label')}")
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
a[0].click()
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
        if window_handle != original_window:
            driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            break

wait.until(EC.none_of(EC.url_contains("news.google.com")))

print(driver.current_url)
```

---

NOTE: I removed the sleep. Sleeps are a bad practice because they aren't "smart." They always wait the same amount of time no matter what's happening. If the thing you are waiting for isn't available yet, you'll get an error. If it's available early, you still wait the full sleep. Instead read up on [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and use the various `ExpectedConditions` to handle the majority of situations you'll need to handle.

Comment: Pretty sure the question is about how to get the real url for an article, which is just a matter of deobfuscating the URL without ever "clicking" anything. It's just a base64 encoded string inside Google's URL.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's what my answer does... it gets the "real" URL using the code OP started with... by clicking the article and getting the URL. I don't know what else they plan to do on that page. This is a work in progress because I already answered the first question which lead to this one. The code OP is using is (mostly) the code I wrote in the answer to his first question.

Comment: It relies on actually visiting URLs, though, which means incurring network traffic and load times for something that doesn't need it. So the downvote is not because your code doesn't work (as you say, it does) but because of _how_ it works.

Comment: We can't take back downvotes. SO literally won't let you after 5 minutes (unless you edit your answer. Then I can. But that said: yes, if you think my answer doesn't answer the question, then you _absolutely should_ downvote it. That's specifically what votes are for, and lets future visitors home in on good answers outside of whether they're accepted)

Answer (score 0):

Google news URLs are redirects with the actual article's URL in them, but "disguised" using base64 encoding. They're trivially extracted, though:

1. Take the URL google gives you, e.g. `https://news.google.com/articles/CBMidGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmN0dm5ld3MuY2Evc2NpLXRlY2gvc3BhY2V4LXJvY2tldC1leHBsb3Npb24taWxsdXN0cmF0ZXMtZWxvbi1tdXNrLXMtc3VjY2Vzc2Z1bC1mYWlsdXJlLWZvcm11bGEtMS42MzY1MzEz0gEA?hl=en-CA&gl=CA&ceid=CA%3Aen`
2. remove the `https://news.google.com/articles/` prefix
3. remove the `?....` query arguments
4. convert what's left from base64 to regular text, and strip the special code prefix/suffix in the resultant URL (it has some control codes at the start and end that Google presumably does *something* with, but we don't care what that something is).

```py
import base64

google_url = "https://news.google.com/articles/CBMiZmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnB1c2hzcXVhcmUuY29tL2d1aWRlcy9ob3Jpem9uLWZvcmJpZGRlbi13ZXN0LWJ1cm5pbmctc2hvcmVzLWFsbC1kZWx2ZXJzLXRyaW5rZXRzLWxvY2F0aW9uc9IBAA?hl=en-CA&gl=CA&ceid=CA%3Aen"
base64_url = google_url.replace("https://news.google.com/articles/","").split("?")[0]
actual_url = base64.b64decode(base64_version)[4:-3].decode('utf-8')
```

Results in `actual_url` being `https://www.ctvnews.ca/sci-tech/spacex-rocket-explosion-illustrates-elon-musk-s-successful-failure-formula-1.6365313`

Comment: both solutions are valid in my eyes, having multiple options to solve this problem is always wanted. Thank you both for the assistance.

Comment: do note I would like to give both solutions the green checkmark if I could.

Comment: I do wonder, can you explain how you were able to come up with your solution?

Comment: I inspected the google news DOM and page source, saw it contained what looked like base64 code, wrote some JS that strips and converts the string, and then verified that the URLs actually resolved to the what the base64 value contained. In terms of the check mark though: remember that when you use SO you're not asking "for yourself", you're asking "for yourself _and all future visitors with the same problem_ because while both might work for you, the important part is to make sure the question, as written (or after editing for focus) is answered by whichever answer you accept.